# Facebook Share Dialog in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6, share

I am trying to implement the [native Share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/ios/share-dialog/) from Facebook in a sample application.

Seem to have some problem in doing so.

Things I have done so far:

1. Included the latest Facebook SDK
2. Included the AdSupport, Social, Account, Security and libsqlite3.dylib.
3. Added the sample code from Facebook.
4. Added -lsqlite3.0 -ObjC to Other Linker Flags as well
5. Added the app id to the plist
6. Added the FBUserSettingsViewResources bundle and FacebookSDKResources.bundle to the project

But I can't seem to share the URL. The share dialog doesn't even appear.

My code looks like this:

Viewcontroller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *buttonShare;
}
- (IBAction)shareButtonClicked:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (IBAction)shareButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    FBShareDialogParams *params = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];
    params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.facebook.com/ios"];
    params.picture = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png"];
    params.name = @"Facebook SDK for iOS";
    params.caption = @"Build great apps";
    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:params clientState:nil handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
        if(error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Success!");
        }
    }];
}
@end
```

Not able to share the URL. Need some guidance on this.

Comment: What version of the Facebook app are you using?

Comment: @MingLi  How do you check that?

Comment: In your phone settings, scroll down to Facebook, and it should show you the version in the details there (note you may have 2 Facebook buttons due to iOS6 integration AND the Facebook app).

Answer (score 1):

```
- (IBAction)shareButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes

    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alertView show];
         }
         else if(session.isOpen)
         {
             NSString *str_img = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png"];

             NSDictionary *params = @{
                                      @"name" :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Facebook SDK for iOS"],
                                      @"caption" : @"Build great Apps",
                                      @"description" :@"Welcome to iOS world",
                                      @"picture" : str_img,
                                      @"link" : @"",
                                      };

             // Invoke the dialog
             [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                    parameters:params
                                                       handler:
              ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                  if (error) {
                      //NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
                      [self.indicator stopAnimating];
                  } else {
                      if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                          //NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                          [self.indicator stopAnimating];
                      } else {
                          //NSLog(@"Story published.");
                          [self.indicator stopAnimating];
                      }
                  }}];
         }

     }];

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Facebook App installed on your device? The Share dialog only works if you have the Facebook app installed.

From the Share dialog documentation :

> Tip 1: What if people don't have the Facebook app installed?
>
> > The Share dialog can't be displayed if people don't have the Facebook app installed. Apps can detect this by calling `[FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:nil];` and may disable or hide a sharing button or fall back to the Feed dialog to share on the web. See the HelloFacebookSample included with the iOS SDK for an example.

From what I saw, iOS 6 will return `NO` for `+ canPresentShareDialogWithParams:`. It only responds to `+ canPresentOSIntegratedShareDialogWithSession:`. But I could be wrong here.

**Anyways, this is how I do it -**
1. For sharing links :

```
if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:nil]) {

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:link.url];
    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:url
                              handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                 if(error) {
                       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                 } else {
                       NSLog(@"Success");
                 }
     }];
}
```

2.For OpenGraph calls :

```
id<FBGraphObject> pictureObject =
    [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"your_namespace:picture"
                                            title:image.title
                                            image:image.thumbnailUrl
                                              url:image.url
                                      description:@""];

    id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
    [action setObject:pictureObject forKey:@"picture"];

    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:action
                                          actionType:@"your_namespace:action_name"
                                 previewPropertyName:@"picture"
                                             handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                 if(error) {
                                                     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                 } else {
                                                     NSLog(@"Success");
                                                 }
                                             }];
```

Check out other ways to share on iOS [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are u able share using sharedialog with the above code? btw, what do u use FBGraphObject or OpenGraph calls for?

Comment: Yes I am able to share without a problem. Open graph calls can be used to create stories. For ex. you could post something like 'user created a recepie on your_app'. Google it.

Comment: Does `presentShareDialogWithLink` handler get invoked after the user has completed the action?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
NSString *url = @"myUrl";
FBLinkShareParams* params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc]init];
params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

if([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params]){
        [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:  [NSURL URLWithString:url]
        name:   @"Name"
        caption:    @"Caption"
        description:    @"Description"
        picture:    nil
        clientState:    nil
        handler:    nil];
    }

    else{
          [...]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)btn_facebook:(id)sender {
    [self performSelector:@selector(fb_func) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}

-(void)fb_func
{
    // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes

    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alertView show];
         }
         else if(session.isOpen)
         {
             NSString *str_link = @"";
             NSLog(@"%@",str_link);

             NSDictionary *params = @{
                                      @"name" :@"name",
                                      @"caption" : @"Description",
                                      @"description" :@"test",
                                      @"picture" : PostimageToPintresrAndFacebook,
                                      @"link" : @"url",
                                      };

             // Invoke the dialog
             [FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                                    parameters:params
                                                       handler:
              ^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                  if (error) {
                      NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
                  } else {
                      if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                          NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
                      } else {
                          NSLog(@"Story published.");
                      }
                  }}];
         }
     }];
    return;

}
```