# In which iOS does Facebook Share Dialog work in?

Tags: ios, facebook, ios5, ios6, share

I intend to use Facebook Share Dialog(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/#sharedialog) for my application and interested to know whether it supports iOS5 or it is only for iOS6 and above?

Comment: It's supported on any iOS version that the Facebook app supports, which does include iOS5.

Comment: Add it as answer... I will upvote...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's supported on any iOS version that the Facebook app supports, which does include iOS5.

Make sure you get the latest version from the app store.

Answer (score 1):

`SLComposeViewController` is only available in iOS6 if that's what you mean?

`UIActivityViewController` is also only available in iOS6.

If you're using less than iOS 6.0 then you'll have to fall back on the Facebook SDK etc...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/share-dialogs-ios-sdk/#sharedialog -> I mean this...

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought you meant the built in Facebook stuff. Although this link https://developers.facebook.com/ios/share-dialog/ says it is for iOS3.5+

Comment: have a look at my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921010/facebook-share-dialog-in-ios