# "FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos" always returning NO

Tags: ios, facebook

Is there some setup that needs to be done before calling [FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos] specifically? Here is what I have, and it's confusing me to why canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos is returning NO.

```
FBLinkShareParams *p = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
p.link = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developers.facebook.com/ios"];

//canShareFB equals YES
BOOL canShareFB = [FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:p];

//canShareFBPhoto equals NO
BOOL canShareFBPhoto = [FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos];
```

In the documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBDialogs/) it states "canPresentShareDialogWithParams: A return value of YES here indicates that the corresponding presentShareDialogWithParams method will return a non-nil FBAppCall for the same params. And vice versa."

AND

"canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos: A return value of YES here indicates that the corresponding presentShareDialogWithPhotoParams method will return a non-nil FBAppCall."

These appear to be almost the exact same conditions. Why does one return YES and the other returns NO?

Comment: This is particularly weird because [FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithOpenGraphActionParams:nil]; returns yes, and even http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921010/facebook-share-dialog-in-ios recommends to use share dialog with open graph for sharing photos. From this I'm inferring that "[FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos]" is simply broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking into the Facebook iOS SDK and found this https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/3096a04ba70837b947725607d925b164d25e8d05/src/DeviceAPI/FBAppBridgeScheme.m particularly the function "bridgeSchemeForFBAppForShareDialogPhotos". My problem was the Facebook app I was using was not updated to the latest version, and did not support Photo Sharing Dialogs.